# Phone Interview when I am out of country

Tags: interviewing, united-states

I have a phone interview but I am out of country for vacation so my number will not work.
Should I ask the interviewer to conduct a hangouts/skype interview or is it correct to ask the interviewer to call on my international number for the interview.

Thanks

Comment: You might consider that the people making the calls may just choose the easiest to get to... and if yours is not the easiest one on the list...

Comment: Don't overthink it. Just let the interviewer know how to reach you.

Answer (score 9):

There's no right answer on this one. I would give them the options that are available to you on your travels. I'm sure they will match/use what's available to them (based on company policy, budget, etc.). Just be courteous in your communication. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As others have said you want to make this as easy as possible on the interviewer - throwing unnecessary obstacles in the way is never a good strategy IMO.

Why not simply explain that you're going to be away on vacation and ask them what their preferred method would be? Give them some options.

> is it correct to ask the interviewer to call on my international number for the interview.

I'd be wary of this - a phone interview can be a relatively lengthy call and depending on what telephony solution the interviewing company has this could get very expensive for them very quickly!

Comment: +1, I have interviewed for jobs while abroad and this is exactly what I did. I never found anyone who wasn't willing to "meet me halfway".